# Comprehensive sketch file for Material Design Keyboards?

Tags: android, input-fields, keyboard, material-design

I have searched high and low and cannot find a comprehensive .sketch file (or any typeof file) containing all *english language* android keyboards with all possible states for a variety of device dimensions....

Examples of useful keyboards that I'd like to see in one place...

- Alphabetic keyboard
- Special Characters keyboard
- Additional Special characters keyboard
- Emoji keyboard
- Telephone keyboard
- Numeric Keyboard
- Password Keyboard
- Speech-to-text keyboard (+ waiting for speech, listening to speech, backspace focused, setting focused, cancel focused)
- *Other keyboards I've missed*

Additionally, take any of the above examples (save for speech) and add as suffix:

- ... with autocorrect on (+ autocorrect option focused, long pressed)
- ... with autocorrect menu open (+ additional autocorrect option focused)
- ... with initiate Search button (+ focused, longpress)
- ... with Carriage Return Button (+ focused, longpress)
- ... with Send button (+ focused, longpress)
- ... with other little-green-action-buttons I've missed (+ focused, longpress)
- ... with key(s) being pressed (+ long-pressed, i.e. regular key focused)
- ... with key(s) being long-pressed (i.e. special characters)

Does anyone have a file such as this? It would be incredibly useful for prototyping and creating training materials.

**If not**, please vote up if you'd find it useful and I will create it and make it available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I know to what you're looking for is [**Material Design UI Kit**](http://Material%20Design%20UI%20Kit) and [Android Lollipop UI Kit Sketch Resource](http://www.sketchappsources.com/free-source/1039-android-lollipop-ui-kit-sketch-freebie-resource.html), both of them made by Ivan Bjelajac, but I doubt you'll find something with all possible states, so if you're in the mood for doing it, I'd say go on and do it!